# What is the proper way to install ZooKeeper on Ubuntu 16.04 for both standalone and multi-node deployment?

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation

First, please consider me as a complete Linux newbie. All of the work I've shown here are cobbled together from various sources from the Internet.

I'm trying to set up a ZooKeeper service with installation steps for development machines (running Ubuntu guest OS on VirtualBox) that can also be easily used in production scenario (ie. only by modifying the config file). These are the steps I've taken, questions are at the bottom.

Install Java:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Make a zookeeper system user:

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-password --disabled-login zookeeper
```

Use wget to download the binary release:

```
wget "http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.10/zookeeper-3.4.10.tar.gz"
```

Create the appropriate directories:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/zookeeper
sudo mkdir /var/lib/zookeeper
sudo mkdir /var/lib/zookeeper/logs
sudo mkdir /var/run/zookeeper
```

Extract the tar archive:

```
sudo tar -xvzf zookeeper-3.4.10.tar.gz --directory /opt/zookeeper --strip-components 1
```

Edit the configuration:

```
sudo cp /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo_sample.cfg /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
sudo nano /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
```

Change the dataDir config option to dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper

Edit the environment script:

```
sudo nano /opt/zookeeper/bin/zkEnv.sh
```

Add this line to the top of the file: ZOO_LOG_DIR="/var/lib/zookeeper/logs"

Ensure permissions:

```
sudo chown -R zookeeper:nogroup /opt/zookeeper
sudo chown -R zookeeper:nogroup /var/lib/zookeeper
sudo chown -R zookeeper:nogroup /var/run/zookeeper
```

Create a systemd service file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service
```

File content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache ZooKeeper
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/zookeeper/zookeeper.pid
User=zookeeper
Group=nogroup
ExecStart=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh stop
Restart=on-failure
SyslogIdentifier=zookeeper

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Question:
When I start the service using "sudo systemctl start zookeeper", the server starts and immediately shuts down. Is there something wrong in the setup above? Are there things that I can do differently to improve these steps (ie. from security stand point)?

I tried using "sudo apt-get install zookeeperd" and found a couple snags, one is that the directory location is confusing and not to my liking, and two, I could not connect to the server from a different machine (connection timeout) even though the server responds with "imok" to the "ruok" telnet test both on localhost and from the remote machine (the server runs fine if I call "./zkServer.sh start" manually).

EDIT:
This is the console output when I tried to run the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl start zookeeper
$ sudo systemctl status zookeeper
● zookeeper.service - Apache Zookeeper
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Apr 11 06:47:42 Ubuntu64 systemd[1]: Started Apache Zookeeper.
Apr 11 06:47:42 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1871]: ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Apr 11 06:47:42 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1871]: Using config: /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1871]: Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1891]: ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1891]: Using config: /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1891]: Stopping zookeeper ... STOPPED
$ sudo journalctl -u zookeeper.service
-- Logs begin at Rab 2018-04-11 06:45:32 WIB, end at Rab 2018-04-11 06:55:55 WIB. --
Apr 11 06:47:42 Ubuntu64 systemd[1]: Started Apache Zookeeper.
Apr 11 06:47:42 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1871]: ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Apr 11 06:47:42 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1871]: Using config: /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1871]: Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1891]: ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1891]: Using config: /opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
Apr 11 06:47:43 Ubuntu64 zookeeper[1891]: Stopping zookeeper ... STOPPED
$
```

Comment: @user68186 Thank you for the `journalctl` tip, I've updated my question the question to include the console output.

Answer (score 1):

This minimal change from `start` to `start-foreground` might be sufficient:

`ExecStart=/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground`

Answer (score 0):

check permissions for dataDir (zoo.cfg) , if the user cannot write in that directory, the service will not start

Comment: Could you insert the specific line in the answer you'd like to see, please?